Handling Errors When Invoking PowerShell Script from C#?
I am trying to invoke a powershell script that makes use of tokens.
var results = powerShell.Invoke();
if (powerShell.HadErrors)
{
    foreach (var error in powerShell.Streams.Error)
    {                            
        ErrorLog.LogError("Error in invoking powershell script " + error.ToString());
        if(error.Exception.Message.Contains("The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."))
        {
            //Recreate the tokens
        }

    }
}

I see, I receive the above specific error message.
Is just checking this specific message fine?
If yes, what if they change the message in the future or perhaps the system language is different.
I also checked the Exception class, it is WebException class.

you can use Exception.Response.StatusCode cast as int and then switch on each error code to handle them

You can handle these exceptions by looking at the HttpWebResponse.StatusCode property. Here is an example:
void HandleWebException(WebException webException)
{
    HttpWebResponse? response = webException.Response as HttpWebResponse;
    if (response is not null)
    {
        switch (response.StatusCode)
        {
            case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                // handle 401
                break;
            case HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests:
                // handle 429
                break;
            // case etc...
        }
    }
}

void HandleWebException(Exception exception)
{
    // handle general exceptions
}

PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
var results = powerShell.Invoke();

if (powerShell.HadErrors)
{
    foreach (var error in powerShell.Streams.Error)
    {
        HandleWebException(error.Exception);
    }
}

